# Distinguishing relationships based on DNA numbers and age difference?

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com

I recently joined Ancestry and received several first to second cousin matches, all from what appears to be the same family. The strongest match is 1070 centimorgams and 45 segments. This woman is about 10 years older than me. I am 60 years old. Am trying to figure out if she could be my grandfathers child or his grandchild, or possibly my Uncles child. My parents are still alive but refuse to be tested. I could contact my cousins, my uncles children but reluctant to, as this may be upsetting to them and I am not close with them.

Any suggestions on narrowing this down based on the DNA numbers and age relationships?

My match has not responded to my inquiry.

Answer (score 2):

Entering your shared [1070 Centimorgans into the Shared cM Project tool](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1070) at DNA Painter suggests a number of possible relationships.

Since you appear to be roughly part of the same generation (10 years difference) I think that you should first explore the possibility of being first cousins, and if you can eliminate that as being a possibility, then look into whether Half Aunt/Uncle or Half Niece/Nephew might be possible.

Contacting the woman you match with, and asking her if she knows your relationship, may be the quickest way forward.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using your age, try to use your grandfather and uncle's ages.

For example, use information about when your grandfather was married and when he had his children and where he was during those years to deduce the possible years when he could have had another unknown child. Do the same for your uncle.

Additionally for your grandfather, for the possible years he could have had a child, add 20 to 40 to that for when his grandchildren could have been born.

See if any of those date ranges correspond to the year your match would have been born.

This won't be proof of anything, but it could eliminate some possibilities or make some more feasible than others.